# Break Inheritance Of Permissions on site - SharePoint 2010

Tags: permissions, solution-package

Good day,

I have saved a site as a template and would like to enforce it that when a new site is created based on that template, the groups on the new site are like the ones on the template.

I have imported the wsp into Visual Studio but now I am stuck.

Is it possible to set this programmatically somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event receiver to run on WebProvisioned. 
Then use the SPWeb.RoleDefinitions.BreakInheritance(true,true).

Comment: Would it be possible to apply this to the wsp template? I am importing it into Visual Studio.

Comment: you can create a feature which triggers this particular code